# Differences between pointers

Tags: c++

I know how the code work. But does not know Why?

What are the differences between pointers?

```cpp
struct List{
   int val;
   List *next;
}
/// where is the different between fun1 and fun2 receiving the List
void fun1(List **head){}
void fun2(List *head){}
int main(){
    List *head;
     /// where is the different between fun1 and fun2 passing the List
    fun1(&head);
    fun2(head);
}
```

Comment: A pointer, is a variable that stores the memory address as its value.
So `*head` stores address of the `List`.  `**head` stores address of `*head`.

Comment: In the case of `fun1`, the variable `head` is passed by value. In the case of `fun2`, it is passed by reference (using a pointer to the pointer). That way, the function `fun2` has access to the original variable (because it knows its memory address) and is therefore able to change its value, whereas `fun1` cannot change the original variable's value, because it only has a copy of it. Just for clarification: I am using the term "pass by reference" in the general sense. In C++, this term has a slightly different meaning, as it only applies to actual "C++ references", not pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is what memory address you are referencing.

- `fun1(&head);`: the memory address you access is the memory address of the `head` pointer itself.
- `fun2(head);`: the memory address you access is where `head` points to.

Try to output the values of `head` this way:

```cpp
void fun1(List **head){
    cout << "Pointer address: " << head << endl;
    cout << "Head points to: " << *head << endl;
}
void fun2(List *head){
    cout << "Head points to: " << head << endl;
}
```

The output will be something like:

```
Pointer address: 0x7ffeec04e058
Head points to: 0x104f2a036
Head points to: 0x104f2a036
```

By using the `&` operator, you are accessing the memory address of the variable `head`.

Comment: I believe the OP may be asking about the difference between "pass by value" and "pass by reference". However, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

`&` gets the address of something. In this case that something's a pointer to a `List`. A pointer simply holds the address of something. So, the address of a pointer to a thing is a pointer to a pointer of that thing.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand